# Output string containing escape characters

Tags: ruby

I have a string:

```
s = "\t\n"
```

I intend to output:

```
\t\n
```

When I do

```
puts s
```

I see nothing. How should I do it?

Comment: Use single quotes:  '\t\n' . Otherwise escape the character with a backslash :  "\\t\\n"

Comment: I want to change all \ to \\ .However, s.gsub!('\','\\') does not make sense

Comment: Why do you want to output `\t\n`? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

That's because `\n` and `\t` are escape sequences

> A single-quoted strings don’t process ASCII escape codes, and they don’t do string interpolation while double-quoted does both.

So if you want that behaviour, you should do

```
s = '\t\n'
```

Comment: If I can not achieve this when initialization, what should I do?

Comment: @XINLIU initialization of what, some context would help us understand your problem better

Comment: For example, I got the string from a function, so I can not modify " to ' in this way.

Comment: I want to change all \ to \\ .However, **s.gsub!('\','\\')** does not make sense

Comment: The OP is aware that these are escape sequences. The question is how to print them.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `inspect` to see the "raw" escape sequences.

```
s = "\t\n"
puts s.inspect
# >> "\t\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p s # >> "\t\n"
```

or

```
puts s.inspect[1...-1] # >> \t\n
```

Comment: beat you by two seconds, haha